# Why is SendGrid limiting my account to 100 emails per month instead of 100 emails per day?

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid

SendGrid advertises that their free plan offers 100 emails per day.

After a few days of use, I noticed that my emails were no longer being sent out. I checked my account and it was showing this message:

> You have used all 100 monthly emails for your Email API free trial.
>   Upgrade to send more.

Why is it saying "100 monthly emails"? Shouldn't I be getting 100 daily emails like the rest of their website says?

Answer (score 3):

I sent in a support request and received this message:

> In order to receive the 100 emails per day, you'll need to choose the
>   Email API trial or the Marketing Campaigns trial. You can do so by
>   navigating to **Settings** > **Account Details** > **Your Products** > **Start Trial to Send More**.
>
> If you start the trial you will receive 40,000 emails a month, but
>   just for 30 days. Once your 30 day trial period has expired, you will
>   be able to send only up to 100 emails per day (unless you choose to
>   upgrade your account).
>
> If you don't start the trial you will be limited to send only 100
>   emails a month.
>
> On short, you are now able to send only 100 emails a month, and if you
>   start the trial you will be able to send up to 40,000 emails in the
>   first month and 100 emails a day from that point onwards.

So in other words, when you first create your account, it starts out at only 100 emails per month, but you can fix that by starting the trial.

I gave that a shot and now it works as expected.

Note that you're not required to give them your credit card details to sign up for the trial, so there doesn't appear to be any downside to doing so.

I'm not sure why the account doesn't default to 100/day from the beginning. I guess their goal is to make you more interested in their paid plan.